# CSS marquee doesn't work on Safari

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm very happy with the way the marquee works on my [website](https://jimmydance.com/), it works in all browsers except of Safari. What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I can do in order to play the same in Safari as well?

```css
.marquee {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  whitespace: nowrap;
  fontsize: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">bla bla bla</p>
```

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for but I would just put that text onto the header bar. You have more than enough space and marquees are really out dated. If you're dead set on still using a marquee it looks like this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123696/css-animation-works-in-chrome-but-not-safari

Comment: i agree marquee is outdated, where is the time i use <marquee> & <blink> .. :p

Comment: You didn't post enough code to reproduce the issue, please edit it.

Comment: This is all I'm using.

Comment: Google "marquee css animation" in Safari and follow an example that works.

Comment: Thanx for your advice, but I'd like to keep this code and waiting for someone that actually wants to help!

Comment: You didn't post any code that actually references an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the animation part of your code.  Plus, I'm not sure transform is going to work without first creating a wrapper to hide the overflow.  Here's an attempt that uses `text-indent` instead.

```css
.marquee {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    text-indent: 260px;
  }
  100% {
    text-indent: -260px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">bla bla bla</p>
```

EDIT: Here's another approach using a wrapper.

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  display:inline-block;
  
  width: 260px;
}

.marquee span {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee"><span>bla bla bla</span></p>
```

Comment: The 1st code works good for all browsers whilst the 2nd one flows out of the navbar (on Chrome). Thanx again for you effort!