# Marquee replacement doesn't work on Safari 5.1.7 (Windows 10)

Tags: html, css, safari

First, I saw this link with a similar question, but I did use animation in my CSS so the solution there isn't relavant:
[CSS marquee doesn't work on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815386/css-marquee-doesnt-work-on-safari)

Now, my code works fine in Chrome, FireFox, Opera, IE and edge. But on Safari it doesn't (the text doesn't move).

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="format.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>updates</h1>
<div class="microsoft container">
    <p class="marquee">
            update 1
            <br><br>        
            update 2
            <br><br>
            update 3
    </p>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
.container {
    width: 93.5%;
    height: 8em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee {
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover { animation-play-state: paused; }

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   8em }
    100% { top: -11em }
}

/* Make it look pretty */
.microsoft .marquee {
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font: 1em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.microsoft:before, .microsoft::before,
.microsoft:after,  .microsoft::after {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%; height: 2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.microsoft:after, .microsoft::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.microsoft:before, .microsoft::before { top: 0; }

/* Style the links */
.vanity {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font: .75em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.vanity a, .microsoft a {
    color: #1570A6;
    transition: color .5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vanity a:hover, .microsoft a:hover { color: #F65314; }
```

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: You need to use prefixed css, like `-webkit-animation: ....`

Comment: And Safari 5.1.7 is more or less dead, so why target that one? .. Apple stopped support it years ago (Windows version)

Comment: You mean, switching "animation" with "-webkit-animation:"? because I tried it and it doesn't work. And for your second response, I am using Safari 5.1.7 just for checking compatibility of my web for difeerent browsers.

Comment: As `transform` and `@keyframes` also need prefix, you need to check all your CSS properties against the browser versions you target. Also, **don't use Safari 5.1.7** to check for compatibility, it is an outdated one and will not help to make it work on Safari for iOS, quite the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comments, here is an update of your code showing how you need write up the CSS to make it work across browser versions, where CSS properties that needs prefix to target older/different browsers has to be added several times for each version.

```css
.container {
  width: 93.5%;
  height: 8em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marquee {
  top: 6em;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
/* Make it move! */

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 8em
  }
  100% {
    top: -11em
  }
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 8em
  }
  100% {
    top: -11em
  }
}
/* Make it look pretty */

.microsoft .marquee {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font: 1em'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before,
.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before {
  top: 0;
}
/* Style the links */

.vanity {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  font: .75em'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
.vanity a,
.microsoft a {
  color: #1570A6;
  transition: color .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vanity a:hover,
.microsoft a:hover {
  color: #F65314;
}
```

```html
<h1>updates</h1>
<div class="microsoft container">
  <p class="marquee">
    update 1
    <br>
    <br>update 2
    <br>
    <br>update 3
  </p>
</div>
```